# PyQt5 UI "freezes" when updating it too quickly from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a GUI to play videos using the python bindings for VLC, and I've run into a snag with the progress slider. Due to VLC's extreme inaccuracy and inconsistency when it comes to reporting a video's progress, I've been faking the QSlider by simply incrementing it + updating the rest of the UI (which includes multiple QLabels, QLineEdits, and QSpinBoxes) once per frame in a separate thread (not a QThread).

However, something strange has been happening: eventually, the entire UI "freezes"... except the video continues playing, the console continues outputting, and the UI instantly jumps back to life after manually interacting with it (such as by pressing the pause button). Qt is running and keeping track of the current state of the UI, just without painting anything.

I've tried manually updating the UI, manually repainting the UI (which always crashes...?), auto-resizing the UI, running processEvents(), running QTest.qWait(1), but nothing has worked. Using a QTimer to increment the progress bar, however, DOES prevent the UI from freezing, which confirms I'm not crazy. Of course, I can't *actually* use a QTimer though, since even a Qt.PreciseTimer results in... a *very* imprecise timer.

I've read that this is likely caused by Qt mistakenly trying to optimize my code by clumping the rapid updates into one, which would explain why the UI seemingly stops being painted despite clearly being active under the hood.

Though I have a feeling that the solution is probably something obvious (maybe even a different implementation of something I mentioned trying above) that doesn't require a code sample, here's a significantly stripped down version of what I'm currently working with:

```
def setup(self):
    self.progress_thread = Thread(target=self.update_slider_thread, daemon=True)
    self.progress_thread.start()


def update_slider_thread(self):
    current_frame = self.progress_slider.value
    is_playing = self.vlc.player.is_playing
    update_progress = self.update_progress
    while True:
        start = time.time()
        while not is_playing():
            sleep(0.01)
            start = time.time()

        while is_playing() and not self.lock_progress_updates:
            frame_multiplier = self.frame_rate
            next_frame = current_frame() + 1
            if next_frame <= self.frame_count:      # don't update if we're at the end
                update_progress(next_frame)
            delay = self.delay    # frame rate / total frames
            try:
                sleep(0.0001)   # forces time.time() to update (otherwise we get the same "time" for several loops)
                sleep(delay - (time.time() - start) - 0.00075)   # 0.00075 to account for executing this line of code
            except: pass
            finally:
                start = time.time()
                continue


def update_progress(self, frame):
    if self.get_player_state() == vlc.State.Ended:
        if self.ready_to_restart and self.vlc.is_paused:
            self.restart_video(frame=frame, pause=True)
    self.current_time = round(self.duration * (frame / self.frame_count), 2)
    h, m, s, ms = get_hms(self.current_time)
    current_time_string = f'{m:02}:{s:02}.{ms:02}'
    
    # these are just aliases for things like setValue() for each widget (for performance)
    self.set_progress_slider(frame)
    if not self.current_time_text_has_focus(): self.set_current_time_text(current_time_string)
    self.set_hour_spin(h)
    self.set_minute_spin(m)
    self.set_second_spin(s)
    self.set_frame_spin(frame)
```

Comment: Qt is not "trying to optimize" your code. `update()` requests are *scheduled* for performance reasons, but the problem is that you're trying to access the UI from an external thread, and UI elements are *not* thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh Ok so some basics. 1st of all, any interaction with widgets have to happen in main thread. So if you are changing slider value/etc. from daemon/worker thread. Then you are messing up Qt insides.

I would suggest that you use signals/slots. Here is a small example of it

```py
class sliderUpdate(QObject):
    handleUpdate = Signal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        print "Current thread (Should be main thread ) : " QThread.currentThread()
        # Lets conect our signal to function/slot.
        self.handleUpdate.connect(self.doUpdate,Qt.QueuedConnection) # We force it in to QueuedConnection so that Qt pass the data from worker thread to Main thread.
        self.slider = QSlider()
                
    def doUpdate(self,val):
        print "Current thread (Should be main thread ) : " QThread.currentThread()
        self.slider.setValue(val)
        
    def processInThread(self):
        print "Current thread (Should be worker thread ) : " QThread.currentThread()
        self.handleUpdate.emit(10)
```

2nd. If VLC is sending updates A LOT per second. Then you may be bombarding Qt with refresh requests & lagging app. I would suggest implementing some sort of... delayed report... A sudo example :

```
timer = QElapsedTimer()
timer.start()
...
...
if timer.elapsed()>500:
   emit new Value:
   timer.restart() 
else:
   skip, emit on next call if timeout over 500 ms.
```

Comment: QElapsedTimer is not a good choice for that, especially considering that the continuous notifications of VLC would potentially create an overhead. QTimer is the best approach (or, eventually, QBasicTimer) to query the player state at regular intervals. Besides, you never called the `super().__init__()`, the `print` statement is wrong (Python 2 is obsolete!), and classes should always have capitalized names.

Comment: @musicamante I'm not sure what you guys are referring to by "continuous notifications of VLC." Can you please clarify? I'm also not sure why you suggested a QTimer, as I've already explained why this is not an effective solution to my problem.

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflow it's not effective because you're trying to use it in the wrong way. The timer must be created, started and connected in the *main* thread, then it will call a function at regular intervals. That function, then, will eventually compute the time elapsed since the last query to the player's position, and, if it's the same, add a specified amount based on the time started from the last changed position (and, in this case, QElapsedTimer could help). In any case, it will *never* be as precise as you wish, especially if you think that you could update the UI every 1ms.

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflow And that's pretty obvious: not only even the fastest PC and GPU can't update faster than 240Hz (that's more than 4ms), but human eyes can't perceive *actual* differences faster than 40-50Hz (more than 20ms). Also, your "0.00075 to account for executing this line of code" is a pointless assumption: not only it's an arbitrary value that can change *a lot* depending on the computer and the current available processing power, but you're adding a further function (and, then, execution time) to account for the execution time of the previous one.

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflow most importantly, considering that those computation are, normally, very fast, you're not considering the actual time required for the UI to update, which might be *a lot more* than 0.75 millisecond, if the update also demands clearing the buffer and repainting at the same time as other widgets (the label, the progress bar, all other widgets you listed, and even the video frame if software rendering is in use). Considering what said above (refresh rate and human perception), and the fact that VLC is not intended for precise timestamping, all of this is just pointless.